# Storing "remember me" information locally c# (total newbeginner)

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, store

I started programming in c# for a few days ago, so I am a total newbeginner at this. Based on my experience in other languages, I found it somewhat "simple".

I am building a system where users are logging in to my application, which is working. I want to have a "remember me"-setting where the information is stored locally. What is the best way to do this? I'll only save the username and the password-hash.

Edit: This is a desktop-application. The login-information is sent to a php-script simply using `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: Not sure what that means...I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Win7. The information is submitted to a php-file

Comment: How do you "submit" the information?

Comment: Is this a web or desktop application? What information is submitted, to where, by a PHP file? Which part of your system is in PHP, and which is in C#?

Comment: @Shai : May not be the best way to do this, but I am simply using HttpWebRequest and sending the information using GET

Comment: @djacobson : It's desktop. The database is mysql and I've made a simple framework in PHP which the application is connecting to.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I think you should revise your question and add more information.

Comment: @Shai : Thanks. I've added some more now. Is it clearer now? Sorry for being unclear on my wishes. There are more sides to c# than I was aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) Class to manage your application's settings.

you can use this function to add new Keys to your configuration file:

```
public bool setSetting(string pstrKey, string pstrValue)
{
    Configuration objConfigFile =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    bool blnKeyExists = false;

    foreach (string strKey in objConfigFile.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
    {
        if (strKey == pstrKey)
        {
            blnKeyExists = true;
            objConfigFile.AppSettings.Settings[pstrKey].Value = pstrValue;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!blnKeyExists)
    {
        objConfigFile.AppSettings.Settings.Add(pstrKey, pstrValue);
    }
    objConfigFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    return true;
}
```

and then save up your username (for example)

```
setSetting("username", usernameTextBox.Text);
```

Once your application starts up, you can read the information you saved earlier from your `ConfigurationManager`

```
usernameTextBox.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
```

Comment: CAUTION: Don't do this with your users' passwords though, obviously. Typically you'd receive a token from the website and store that, instead. This is still dodgy ground though from a security perspective.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell : What is I hash the password before storing it? Security is not a huge deal in the application. It's more like a gimmick because I want to learn it. But a token could work too :)

Comment: The problem is that regardless of whether you hash it, someone could steal the entire file and copy it as-is to their own machine to pretend they are someone else. You can eliminate this somewhat by salting the hashed value with something taken from the environment. It's basically the same problem you can have with browser cookies, so I guess investigating how browsers tackle these issues is worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP .NET,you can set authentication cookie when you're logged in user by second parameter

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
```

Second parameter sets cookie to your request and makes "Remeber Me" option.

Comment: Does this work for desktop applications? I was a bit unclear on my application.

Answer (score 0):

you can create Application Settings in C#

[here's what you will do.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

don't forget to encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is, php file is server and for client you are using windows form. Your are doing some kind of HTML scrapping and displaying the result HTML in your win-form. If this is the what you are doing then

```
//1. Create a dictionary to store cookie collection

    public static Dictionary<string, Cookie> CookieCollection { get; set; }

//2. Store cookie in that collection


foreach (Cookie clientcookie in response.Cookies)
     {
                    if (!CookieCollection.ContainsKey("AuthCookieName"))
                        CookieCollection .Add(userName, clientcookie);
                    else
                        CookieCollection ["userName"] = clientcookie;
    }

//3. If remember me is clicked then send the same while creating request

    request.CookieContainer.Add(request.RequestUri, 
new Cookie("AuthCookieName", CookieCollection ["userName"]));
```

Where AuthCookieName is the name of authentication cookie. The only downside is when the application exists all the cookie stored in the dictionary would be gone. The solution could be serializing the cookie and storing it in database, if remember me is checked.