# How to modify the App.Config section value

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have an app.config like below,

```
<configuration>
    <environment>
        <add key="security" value="1"/> -- I want to change this value to 3
    </environment>
</configuration>
```

I tried like below to get to environment section,

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
var environment = config.GetSection("environment");
```

environment variable doesn't give me enough options to get the child elements to modify the value.  Could any one please help me out in this one.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785502/storing-remember-me-information-locally-c-sharp-total-newbeginner/8785646) question

Comment: What is the type of the `environment` configuration section?

Comment: @Oded it doesn't have any type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use user scope settings!! NEVER EVER change the application configuration that way. Any value that is changed within the application should be a user setting.

Usually, you access these settings through

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyConfigurationValue = ....;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**EDIT**
Sample for doing what I wrote in the comments. Create two user settings: `FirstRun` is a `bool` which is by default set to `true`. `Environment` is your value, by default set to  `0`.

Then, for example in the `Main` function in `Program.cs` you'd do the following:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
    if (myConditionIsTrue)
        Properties.Settings.Default.Environment = 3;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Later in your application it is enough to use `Properties.Settings.Default.Environment`. That's how the settings mechanism is intended to be used if you want to change configuration values from your application.

Under Windows 2000, XP, 7 and the Windows Server branch you would not even have the rights to modify the app.config in your Program Files folder, so don't!

Comment: But in my case I want to modify that value. I am modifying those at install time of an application based on some condition.

Comment: What's the condition? The proper way would be to have user setting provide a default value. Then upon first running the application, the correct value is determined based on the condition. Things might be different if you're using a setup application that modifies the configuration file before copying to the user's system. In that case, you're talking about modifying a simple XML file, which has nothing to do with settings mechanisms at all. If you want to use the settings mechanisms, you should use them properly.

Comment: At install time I need to query the registry and read a particular value , put that value inside the app.config. I am using Installer class to achieve this. 

Yes I am using setup application.

Comment: Well, then it's really not a matter of reading the config file using the `ConfigurationManager`. You can then treat the file like any other XML file and modify it using for example `XmlDocument`. However, I don't see why you can't use the mechanism I suggested in my edits - reading the Registry should be fine in your code as well. Why does it need to be done at install time?

Comment: Ok thanks Thorsten, I will try the XmlDocument way (which seems simpler to me).

Comment: "NEVER EVER change the application configuration that way. Any value that is changed within the application should be a user setting."

While this is generally correct, "NEVER EVER" is too strong a phrase. "Most of the time" or even "in all but a few cases" is more appropriate. There is always that case of the system-level app that needs to run under multiple user accounts (or machine/service accounts) and which needs the flexibility of settings that can be changed globally as conditions change. I've worked on several. Not all apps are designed for individual users on individual workstations.

Comment: @Wing I'd dare say "you're doing it wrong then". An application is simply not allowed to write anything to the `Program Files` folder (apart from setups, of course). If you need to do what you say the Microsoft way is to store these settings in the common application data folder.